Detecting chemical groups from smiles using Smart
Currently I am working on a code that should be able to detect chemical groups in a molecule and list them after being given the smiles of the molecule as input.
Overall the code works great, but the code has issues when detecting cycles either aromatic, hetero cycles and even the ring in cyclohexanol. The same issue is there for alkenes, while either it detects only the alkene, but it cannot differentiate between cis and trans or aromatics.
Could someone tell me what smarts patterns I could use to find cycles and even differentiate them depending on the ring sizes and maybe also define specifics such as if hetero atoms are present and if the ring is aromatic? And a solution for determining the difference between cis and trans alkenes.
My code has a very long list of functional groups but I will just add a few here, so you know how it looks like:
from rdkit import Chem

def find_smiles_patterns(smiles):
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    if mol is None:
        return "Invalid SMILES string. Unable to parse molecule."

    # Define a list to store the chemical groups found in the SMILES
    chemical_groups = []

    # SMARTS patterns to recognize chemical groups
    smarts_patterns = {
        'C=C': 'Alkene',
    '[CX2]#[CX2]': 'Alkyne',
    '[CX3]=[CX2]=[CX3]': 'Allene',
    '[ClX1][CX4]': 'Alkylchloride',
    '[FX1][CX4]': 'Alkylfluoride',
    '[BrX1][CX4]': 'Alkylbromide',
    '[IX1][CX4]': 'Alkyliodide',
    '[OX2H][CX4H2;!$(C([OX2H])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Primary_alcohol',
    '[OX2H][CX4H;!$(C([OX2H])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Secondary_alcohol',
    '[OX2H][CX4D4;!$(C([OX2H])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Tertiary_alcohol',
    '[OX2]([CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15,F,Cl,Br,I])])[CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Dialkylether',
    '[SX2]([CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15,F,Cl,Br,I])])[CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Dialkylthioether',
    '[OX2](c)[CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15,F,Cl,Br,I])]': 'Alkylarylether',
    '[c][OX2][c]': 'Diarylether',
    '[SX2](c)[CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15,F,Cl,Br,I])]': 'Alkylarylthioether',
    '[c][SX2][c]': 'Diarylthioether',
    '[O+;!$([O]~[!#6]);!$([S]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Oxonium',
    '[NX3H2+0,NX4H3+;!$([N][!C]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Primary_aliph_amine',
    '[NX3H1+0,NX4H2+;!$([N][!C]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Secondary_aliph_amine',
    '[NX3H0+0,NX4H1+;!$([N][!C]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Tertiary_aliph_amine',
    '[NX4H0+;!$([N][!C]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Quaternary_aliph_ammonium',
    '[!#6;!R0]': 'Heterocyclic'
    #etc....
    }

    # Define priority order for chemical groups based on IUPAC nomenclature
    priority_order = [
    'Carboxylic_acid',
    'Carboxylic_ester',
    'Lactone',
    'Carboxylic_anhydride',
    'Carbothioic_acid',
    'Aldehyde',
    'Ketone',
    'Alkylchloride',
    'Alkylfluoride',
    'Alkylbromide',
    'Alkyliodide',
    'Alcohol',
    'Primary_alcohol',
    'Secondary_alcohol',
    'Tertiary_alcohol',
    'Dialkylether',
    'Alkene',
    'Alkyne',
    'Allene',
    'Dialkylthioether',
    'Alkylarylether',
    'Diarylether',
    'Alkylarylthioether',
    'Diarylthioether',
    'Oxonium',
    'Primary_aliph_amine',
    'Secondary_aliph_amine',
    'Tertiary_aliph_amine',
    'Quaternary_aliph_ammonium',
    'Heterocycle'
    #etc......
    ]


    # Track the atom indices to avoid duplicates
    atom_indices = set()
    
    # Iterate over the priority order and check if each chemical group is present in the molecule
    for group in priority_order:
        if group in smarts_patterns.values():
            for smarts_pattern, chemical_group in smarts_patterns.items():
                if chemical_group == group:
                    pattern = Chem.MolFromSmarts(smarts_pattern)
                    if pattern:
                        
                        matches = mol.GetSubstructMatches(pattern)
                        
                        if len(matches) > 0:
                            
                            print('matches !!! : ', smarts_pattern , smarts_patterns[smarts_pattern], pattern)
                            
                            print(matches,'\n\n')
                            
                            for match in matches:
                                match_set = set(match)
                                if not any(atom_index in match_set for atom_index in atom_indices):
                                    chemical_groups.append(chemical_group)
                                    atom_indices.update(match_set)

    return chemical_groups



smiles = "c1(cccc2c1ccc1c2cccc1CCl)CO"

print(find_smiles_patterns(smiles))


Used on invented molecule:

SMILES: c1(cccc2c1ccc1c2cccc1CCl)CO
Results:
matches !!! :  [ClX1][CX4] Alkylchloride <rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol object at .............>
((15, 14),) 

matches !!! :  [OX2H][CX4H2;!$(C([OX2H])[O,S,#7,#15])] Primary_alcohol <rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol object at .............>
((17, 16),) 

['Alkylchloride', 'Primary_alcohol']

I did try change the Smarts, I also tried to do a placeholder function for detecting rings with a function checking a smiles of the form C1[X]nX1, while n is 2-8 and X is in the atom list: C, N, O, S
However nothing worked so far and it seems that there is no database for the smarts.
ADDENDUM
Atom index on the SMILES: c1(cccc2c1ccc1c2cccc1CCl)CO ,
should be this one, but please doublecheck


did you have a look at here https://www.rdkit.org/docs/RDKit_Book.html :Aromaticity is one of those unpleasant topics that is simultaneously simple and impossibly complicated. .... Instead of using patterns to match known aromatic systems, the aromaticity perception code in the RDKit uses a set of rules. The rules are relatively straightforward.Aromaticity is a property of atoms and bonds in rings. An aromatic bond must be between aromatic atoms, but a bond between aromatic atoms does not need to be aromatic. For example the fusing bonds here are not considered to be aromatic by the RDKit...

https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13321-022-00616-5 PIKAChU: a Python-based informatics kit for analysing chemical units from the paper seems like It can highlight rings so it should be able to find them as a patter ?? cant find relevant documentation though. Try here  https://github.com/BTheDragonMaster/pikachu/blob/b71f38fe74876f197bf3d8cfd0df1c7a14d21674/build/lib/pikachu/chem/structure.py#L758  def find_aromatic_cycles(self): Returns cycles that are aromatic Output -aromatic_cycles: list of[[Atom, ->], ->],with each list of atoms the atoms that comprise an aromatic cycle

@pippo1980 Thank you so much for your comments! I truly appreciate it. I have been trying to modify it a bit and create a new code to tackle the issue with aromaticity and cycles, however I get in trouble once I have annulated cycles.
Like what kind of function would I need that the function also finds cycles, can determined the length and the also list the aromatic rings as well and maybe even select if it has hetero atoms in the rings.
How do I add information so you can check it, what I modified?
But again thanks a lot for the comment so far!

sorry @CedricBaerlocher , no idea , dont have experience with that; but apparently rdkit doesnt have a pre-made solution for your problem , unless third party script based on rdkit solve that ..... I dont even have any idea about alghoritms that do that ,

https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/rdkit-announce/

Hi @pippo1980 I posted a new post with the whole new code that is modified and has some examples that show the issue, maybe you want to have a look at it and tell me if you see what I could improve
